How do I get ZM_AUTH_TOKEN from a ZIMBRA server
I want to scrape my emails from a Zimbra server (version Zimbra 8.8.15_GA_4581, build 20231201091219), but I can't figure out which request provides the ZM_AUTH_TOKEN needed to communicate with the server via code.
Neither the documentation (https://community.zextras.com/zimbra-rest-api/) nor the requests from the browser provide information on how to obtain it.
Is there a way to get this token using a username and password?
